# OpenGL texture from SDL Surface in Go

Tags: go, opengl, textures, sdl-2

I'm using [go-sdl2](https://github.com/veandco/go-sdl2) and [go-gl](https://github.com/go-gl/gl) and I'm trying to create a gl texture from sdl surface. In C I would do that by calling `glTexImage2D` with `surface->pixels` as the last argument. In `go-sdl`, however, `pixels` is a [private field](https://github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/blob/8876723d62c5cb28733b08a9443b45a9ea0956be/sdl/surface.go#L165) and `Pixels()` (that I'm supposed to use to access it) returns `[]byte`, which is incompatible with `gl.TexImage2D` that expects the last argument to be an `unsafe.Pointer`.

```
image, err := img.Load("img.png")
if err != nil {
    //...
}
var texture uint32
gl.GenTextures(1, &texture)
gl.BindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture)
gl.TexImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, image.W, image.H, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.Pixels())
```

> cannot use image.Pixels() (value of type []byte) as type unsafe.Pointer in argument to gl.TexImage2D

So what would be the proper way of creating gl texture from sdl surface in go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is [Surface.Data](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/veandco/go-sdl2@v0.4.24/sdl#Surface.Data) function that returns the actual pointer.

```
gl.TexImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, image.W, image.H, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.Data())
```